# Filter out Tweet from verified accounts while extracting using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to know how to filter out Tweets from verified accounts. I want all other Tweets.

This is what I am using right now:

```
list_tweets = []
args =['Corona']
query = args[0]
if len(args) == 1:
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query+" -filter:retweets",since='2020-04-20', lang='ur',tweet_mode='extended',result_type='mixed').items(5000):
        list_tweets.append(status.full_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Status/[Tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) has a user attribute with a [User object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user) that represents the user who posted the Tweet. You can use the `verified` attribute of each User object for each Tweet to determine if the user has a verified account and manually filter them out.